# How do I filter out a group where there is at least one occurrence of a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sample data below I need to show only records where the **ContactType** is not equal to 'CLOSR' by **caseid_i** but with my code below it filters out anything with CLOSR, but not by the CaseID_I. So if at least one of the Caseid_i has a ContactType of 'CLOSR' I need to filter out the whole CaseID. So for CaseID_i 51709, that caseid_i wouldn't show up in my results at all because at least one of the 'ContactTypes' is CLOSR and the same for 51715.

[image]

```
SELECT C.[cdcpincid_c]
    ,I.[caseid_i]
    ,I.echono_c
    ,C.[close_d] AS ClosureDate
    ,C.[clinician_c] AS ClosureClinician
    ,N.[contacttyp_c] AS ContactType
    ,SC.StaffName AS ClosureStaffName
    ,I.Refdate_d
FROM [cd].[tb_cdcp_case] C
INNER JOIN [cd].[tb_cdcp_incident] I ON I.[uniqueid_c] = C.[cdcpincid_c]
INNER JOIN [cd].[tb_cdcp_clientcontact] N ON I.[uniqueid_c] = N.[cdcpincid_c]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[vCDCP_Staff] SC ON C.clinician_c = SC.Staffcode_c
GROUP BY C.[cdcpincid_c]
    ,I.[caseid_i]
    ,I.echono_c
    ,C.[close_d]
    ,C.[clinician_c]
    ,N.[contacttyp_c]
    ,SC.StaffName
    ,I.Refdate_d
HAVING sum(CASE 
            WHEN N.[contacttyp_c] = 'CLOSR'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) = 0
    AND C.[close_d] IS NOT NULL
    AND I.echono_c <> 'OC'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the condition from the `where` clause and switch it to a `having` clause:

```
having sum(case when ContactType = 'CLOSR' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

EDIT:

I see.  You are returning multiple rows per `caseid`.  In that case, use a window function as well:

```
having sum(sum(case when ContactType = 'CLOSR' then 1 else 0 end)) over (partition by caseid) = 0
```

Comment: I made changes in the code above to include the having clause but it still brings up CaseIDs that had at least one CLOSR ContactType.

Comment: @Dee . . . Your result set has more than one row per `caseid`.  To get all the contacts, a window function can be used.